# scp command inside bash script not working under non-root user

Tags: linux, bash, root, scp, privileges

I wrote a bash script which should move a file to remote server.
this is my code:

```
#!/bin/sh

# ensure running as root
if [ "$(id -u)" != "0" ]; then
  exec sudo "$0" "$@" 
fi

cat <<EOF > /etc/name.txt

EOF

sshpass -p 'password' scp -r /etc/name.txt root@192.168.1.50:/etc/name.txt
```

when I run this script under root user it works perfectly. but when I run this script under non-root user the `scp` part doesn't work. when I check $UID after this part:

```
if [ "$(id -u)" != "0" ]; then
      exec sudo "$0" "$@" 
fi
```

it shows `0` and $USER is `root` which means user changed to root but I don't know why it's not working. Any help?

Comment: The best way to debug shell scripts is by putting `set -x` at the beginning, so you see all the commands as they're executed.

Comment: I disagree that the local user needs to be root. You can create `name.txt` somewhere that doesn't need root access (copying it to `/etc/name.txt` with `sudo cp` if necessary), and the call to `sshpass` doesn't need root access to log into the remote machine as root.

Comment: What do you mean doesn't work, what error it throws on the `stdout`.  Does the script creates a file `/etc/name.txt` ?  Run `scp` with option `-v`.

Comment: Add on system 192.168.1.50 output of `sudo grep Permit /etc/ssh/sshd_config` to your question.

Comment: Thank you guys, my problem was command `sshpass` was not found and I changed it to full path `/usr/local/bin/sshpass` and it was resolved.